# C segmentation fault when entering any sort of for loop after a string pointer is got from a function

Tags: c

I am having an issue I don't understand what the cause is for so the code looks as following

```
int move_directories(char* content1, char* content2)
{
  int i;
  const char *path1 = get_path(content1);
  const char *path2 = get_path(content2);

  for (i=0; i<15; i++)
  {
    printf("test\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see entering even a simple for loop like this gives a segmentation fault, I have no idea what could be causing this is, without the for loops if I print the paths they both give me the correct results so the function seems to be working correctly, but I think it is something happening with memory that I am not seen that could be causing this.

What could the cause of this be, because I am clueless?

Thanks

I have tried entering multiple different things, it seems to be for loops for some reason causing this, if I just do something like print("hello") by itself this is fine, it seems as if something with for loops in particular causing the problem, as even a basic one like that gives errors, what could the problem be? As I could not find any thing that is able to fix this issue

Comment: you need to post a [mcve]

Comment: Segmentation Faults usually produce core dumps, which are full of information you can inspect in a debugger. However if this is just a stack smashing problem (which nobody can tell from the code shown), it's probably quicker to use valgrind or an address sanitizer to help find the culprit.